# Jersey Client API - Getting JavaIOException premature EOF when consuming a service

Tags: java, jersey

I'm using Jersey to implement my webservices. I'm creating a java Client that will consume these services based on Jersey Client API. When I call a webservice that resturns a list of String, a map or a business object ALL is OK and I get the expected response in my client side. However, when calling a webservice returning a String or an int, I get JavaIOException: premature EOF. 
Do you have any idea about this issue please?

I'm instantiating my client in this way :

```
String serviceUrl = "http://localhost:9998";
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
Client client = Client.create(config);
resource = client.resource(serviceUrl + "/infos");
resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
```

The Method I'm calling should return a String :

```
public String getInfo() {
    return resource.get(String.class);
}
```

Here is the error stackTrace :

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:563)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:674)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:191)
    at org.novapost.proto.client.InfoResourceClient.getInfo(InfoResourceClient.java:37)
    at org.novapost.proto.client.TestInfoResourceClient.testGETInfo(TestInfoResourceClient.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:36)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:538)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:582)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:669)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2391)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.readFromAsString(ReaderWriter.java:171)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.readFromAsString(ReaderWriter.java:157)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.readFromAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:114)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.readFrom(StringProvider.java:73)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.readFrom(StringProvider.java:58)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:553) ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Also may be you are call the `response.getEntity`] more than one time that mean you will call closed stream , as the Closeable reader will be closed from first call. So just call `response.getEntity` then use the entity to get resource values.